# When a number $N$ is expressible as a sum of two squares in EXACTLY three ways

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Does there exist an $N$ such that $$N=x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2=x_3^2+y_3^2\neq x_4^2+y_4^2\qquad \land \qquad \begin{cases}\gcd(x_1,y_1)&=1 \\\gcd(x_2,y_2)&=1\\\gcd(x_3,y_3)&=1  \end{cases}$$
???

If such a number $N$ is expressible as a sum of two squares in exactly $3$ and only $3$ ways, is it guaranteed that the second condition above FAILs to be satisfied?

My way of deriving such numbers $N$:

$$\text{if}\quad N=\prod_{i=1}^k\underbrace{p_i^{\alpha_i}}_{{\text{all} \quad 1 \pmod 4\quad \text{primes}}}\qquad \text{then} \qquad r(N)=\frac 1 2 \prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha_i+1)$$
with $r(x)$ being the function which is valued by the number of ways a natural number $x$ is expressible as a sum of two squares in distinct ways (without respect to order, or negatives, also not including $0$).  For only three ways to express $N$, I chose $k=2$ and let the $\alpha_i$ be $1$ and $2$ only.

Examples,
$$\begin{aligned}325&=5^2\cdot 13 &&\to r(325)=3\\ &=1^2+18^2=6^2+17^2=\boxed{10^2+15^2}\\425&=5^2\cdot 17 &&\to r(425)=3 \\&=\boxed{5^2+20^2}=8^2+19^2=13^2+16^2 \\845&=5 \cdot 13^2&&\to r(825)=3 \\&=2^2+29^2=\boxed{13^2+26^2}=19^2+22^2\end{aligned}$$

The below is my first try at a parameterization for the case where $r(N)=3$.
$$\begin{aligned}N&=\left[\frac{(r^2-q^2)u-(2qr)v}{r^2+q^2}\right]^2+\left[\frac{(2qr)u+(r^2-q^2)v}{r^2+q^2}\right]^2\\&=\left[u\right]^2+\left[v\right]^2\\&=\left[\frac{(b^2-c^2)u+(2bc)v}{b^2+c^2}\right]^2+\left[\frac{(2bc)u-(b^2-c^2)v}{b^2+c^2}\right]^2\end{aligned}$$

Derivation, in case of interest:

> $\begin{cases}x_1&=pq+rs \\ y_1&=pr-qs \\ x_2&= pq-rs &&=ab+cd&&&=u \\   y_2&=pr+qs&&= ac-bd&&&=v\\ x_3  & &&=ab-cd \\  y_3& &&=ac+bd \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}ab+cd-pq+rs&=0 \\ ac-bd-pr-qs&=0\end{cases}$
>   $\iff \left[\begin{array}{llll}b&c&-q&r \\ c&-b&-r&-q\end{array}\right]\cdot \left[\begin{array}{l}a \\ d \\ p \\ s\end{array}\right]=\overrightarrow{0}\implies\left[\begin{array}{llll}b&c&-q&r \\ c&-b&-r&-q\end{array}\right]\sim \left[\begin{array}{llll}1 & 0 & -\frac{bq+cr}{b^2+c^2} & \frac{br-cq}{b^2+c^2} \\ 0&1&\frac{br-cq}{b^2+c^2}&\frac{bq+cr}{b^2+c^2}\end{array}\right]\implies$
> $a=\left(\frac{bq+cr}{b^2+c^2}\right)p+\left(\frac{cq-br}{b^2+c^2}\right)s=\frac{b(pq-rs)+c(pr+qs)}{b^2+c^2}=\frac{bu+cv}{b^2+c^2}$
>   $d=\left(\frac{cq-br}{b^2+c^2}\right)p-\left(\frac{bq+cr}{b^2+c^2}\right)s=\frac{-b(pr+qs)+c(pq-rs)}{b^2+c^2}=\frac{cu-bv}{b^2+c^2} \implies$
>   $x_3=ab-cd=\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}\left[b(bu+cv)-c(cu-bv)\right]=\frac{(b^2-c^2)u+(2bc)v}{b^2+c^2}\sim y_3=\frac{(2bc)u-(b^2-c^2)v}{b^2+c^2}$
>   $\begin{cases}u&=pq-rs \\ v&=pr+qs\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}p&=-\frac{qu+rv}{r^2+q^2}\\s&=\frac{ru-qv}{r^2+q^2}\end{cases}$
>   $\implies x_1=\frac{(r^2-q^2)u-(2qr)v}{r^2+q^2},\qquad  y_1=\frac{(2qr)u+(r^2-q^2)v}{r^2+q^2}$

Comment: as long as the number $N$ is odd and not itself a square, your $r(N)$ is correct : in these cases the total number of representations is a multiple of $8$ . Theorem 65 in Dickson, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers (1929)

Comment: When you write, "proportionality between the two numbers," I *think* what you mean is that the two numbers are not relatively prime, that is, they have a common divisor other than $1$. Is that right?

Comment: And what are your "examples" examples of? They are not examples of $r(n)=3$; are they just examples of computing $r(n)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes

Comment: @GerryMyerson the examples where $r(N) \neq 3$ have more to do with a previous edit of this question....

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've edited the old irrelevant examples out

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1157407_overall_look_for_long_equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N=p^2q$ where $p\ne q$ are both primes congruent $1\bmod4$, then there exist unique $a,b$ with $p=a^2+b^2$, $a>b>0$, and $c,d$ with $q=c^2+d^2$, $c>d>0$. Then $p^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2$, and $$\begin{aligned}N&=\left[(a^2-b^2)c+(2ab)d\right]^2+\left[(a^2-b^2)d-(2ab)c\right]^2\\&=\left[(a^2-b^2)d+(2ab)c\right]^2+\left[(a^2-b^2)c-(2ab)d\right]^2\\&=(pc)^2+(pd)^2\end{aligned}$$

Note that $2N$ has the same number of representations as $N$.

Also, if $p$ is a prime congruent $1\bmod4$, then $p^4$ has three representations, e.g., $5^4=625=25^2+0^2=24^2+7^2=20^2+15^2$.

EDIT: Let's look at this over the *Gaussian integers*, ${\bf G}=\{\,a+bi\mid a,b{\rm\ in\ }{\bf Z}\,\}$. Here are some facts we will use without proof. Proofs can be found all over the web, or in many intro Number Theory and Algebraic Number Theory texts.

1. $\bf G$ is an integral domain.
2. The units in $\bf G$ are $\{\,\pm1,\pm i\,\}$. Two elements are called *associates* if their quotient is a unit. The *conjugate* of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$. The conjugate of $z$ is denoted $\overline z$.
3. The primes in $\bf G$ are $1+i$, $a\pm bi$ where $a^2+b^2$ is a $1\bmod4$ prime, each $3\bmod4$ prime, and all their associates.
4. $\bf G$ is a unique factorization domain. In particular, every $1\bmod4$ prime $p$ has a unique factorization (up to associates) $p=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ where $a^2+b^2=p$.

Now, every expression of $N=r^2+s^2$ as a sum of two squares corresponds to a factorization of $N=(r+si)(r-si)$ as a product of a Gaussian integer and its conjugate. In particular, if $N=p^2q$ where $p=a^2+b^2$ and $q=c^2+d^2$ are distinct $1\bmod4$ primes, then $$N=(a+bi)^2(a-bi)^2(c+di)(c-di)$$ and there are three ways to write this as a product of a Gaussian integer and its conjugate:

1. $N=[(a+bi)^2(c+di)]\ [(a-bi)^2(c-di)]$
2. $N=[(a+bi)^2(c-di)]\ [(a-bi)^2(c+di)]$
3. $N=[(a+bi)(a-bi)(c+di)]\ [(a+bi)(a-bi)(c-di)]$

Multiplying everything out, this gives $N=e\overline e$ where $e$ takes on the values

1. $(a^2-b^2)c-2abd+((a^2-b^2)d+2abc)i$,
2. $(a^2-b^2)c+2abd+(-(a^2-b^2)d+2abc)i$,
3. $pc+pdi$.

And that gives our three ways to write $N$ as a sum of two squares.

It's clear that the representation coming from the third option, $N=(pc)^2+(pd)^2$, involves numbers that are not relatively prime.

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$. From that, you can show that only the $(pc)^2+(pd)^2$ is *not* relatively prime. Everything becomes simpler when analyzed in terms of complex numbers (Gaussian integers). We're looking at the different choices of sign in $(a\pm bi)(a\pm bi)(c\pm di)$. If you don't like zero, then $5^5=55^2+10^2=50^2+25^2=41^2+38^2$.

Comment: The parametrization may be similar to yours, but you have all these quantities $r,q,u,v,b,c$ with no indication of where they come from, whereas I tie $a,b,c,d$ explicitly to the representations of $p,q$ as sums of two squares.

Comment: I've added my derivation to the post. I do like your approach, and your parameterization is likely better, but I just don't see how this parameterization proves that there IS NOT some N with the above second property that every (x,y) pair be mutually prime.  Is this the ONLY parameterization possible???

Comment: If $n=p^2q$ then there will be a representation of $n$ obtained by taking the representation of $q=c^2+d^2$ and multiplying both $c$ and $d$ by $p$. So, you can't avoid having a pair that isn't mutually prime. Similar remarks apply to $n=p^5$ and $n=p^6$. $5^6=117^2+44^2=120^2+35^2=100^2+75^2$.

Comment: Does that answer your question about relatively prime pairs?

Comment: If you could edit your answer to make it obvious that it's always the case that one of the pairs will NOT be relatively prime, like how you kind of did it in the comment, I'd appreciate that.  Also I don't know if this is the only parameterization possible.... and if you could show that you'd get the check mark